# create list items with jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2007, caml

Went to the Jan Tielens' Bloggings:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/10/creating-list-items-with-jquery-and-the-sharepoint-web-services.aspx

I've successfully adapted his script. Problem is, I want several input boxes.

This piece:

$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#newTaskButton").click(function() {
                CreateNewItem($("#newTaskTitle").val());
            });
        });

```
   function CreateNewItem(title, Fname) {
        // The CAML to create a new item and set the Title field.
        var batch =
            "<Batch OnError=\"Continue\"> \
                <Method ID=\"1\" Cmd=\"New\"> \
                    <Field Name=\"Title\">" + title + "</Field> \
                    <Field Name=\"FirstName\">" + Fname + "</Field> \
                    </Method> \
            </Batch>";
```

successfully inputs to the list however the "Fname" field returns undefined"

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving it a value, that is why it is undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $("#newTaskButton").click(function() {
         CreateNewItem($("#newTaskTitle").val(), "FNamesvalue"); 
     }); 
});
```

This will goe FName the value of "FNamesValue"

Comment: I agree with your analysis, however I took a newby approach to resolving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This value will return null. because u r passing one parameter.

or do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("#newTaskButton").click(function() { 
CreateNewItem($("#newTaskTitle").val(),FNameValue.val()); }); });
```